# Iframe to display a video

Tags: html

I need to create a side screen to play a video while the user browser my site. But  the video most keep playing while the user load differents pages of the site. Is it possible to be done? How?

I have no idea how to google it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using **[Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))**.

From wikipedia:

> [..] With Ajax, web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.[..]

Other way to make that is, to make a **single page** with all the sections, and with CSS, set the video [position: fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) *(the element is positioned relative to the browser window)* so while the user scroll vertically, the video follow the movement...